# weasyprint with django renders digits as images

Tags: python, django, weasyprint

I'm trying to print an invoice using `python-django 3.0.5` and `django-weasyprint 1.0.1`, using the base method described [here](https://www.bedjango.com/blog/how-generate-pdf-django-weasyprint/).

Both my static files and my stylesheets are loaded correctly. Returning my generated html string as normal django HttpResponse works fine.

However, rendering my content to PDF always renders every digit as low-res image like below:
[image: pdf excerpt]

The numbers are generated as regular text, I would expect them to be rendered as regular text using the same font as the letters around them. Did I miss a setting? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the font in your pdf stylesheet, more specifically the `font-family`. People have had issues with fonts like `Apple Color Emoji` as well as `Segoe UI Emojii` if they are included.

Comment: Oh man...  it could have been so easy... I added `body{
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
}` as a quick test, works like a charm. I will play around with more font-families.  Thank you very much!

I used the twitter bootstrap 4 default fonts before, btw.